# Is there any way to highlight text in the (editable) official FAQ?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, stackexchange-2.0, moderator-abilities

Originally in the FAQ, the "target audience" phrase (i.e. "professional and amateur cooks and chefs" on the [cooking.se FAQ](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/faq)) had a yellow background.  This was accomplished by surrounding it in an HTML tag, specifically `<span class="revision-comment">`, which makes it consistent in appearance with other parts of the FAQ.

It would seem that this text block has been switched from pure HTML to Markdown, and the [span tag is not supported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed).  So even though I add it, and it actually "sticks" (I can see that the tags are still there if I edit it again), it's never actually displayed or even rendered out to the browser.

Is there any workaround for this?  If not, is it possible to whitelist the `<span>` tag for the moderator-editable content areas?

Comment: Not just the span tag... You'll also need the class attribute, which is also normally stripped by SO's Markdown processor.

Comment: @Shog9: Allowed attributes seem to be specific to a tag according to the FAQ.  You're right in that if they allow the tag, they'll have to make that one of the allowed attributes.  Or just code a Markdown-based workaround to get that specific style.

Comment: that would probably be the better option.

Answer (score 1):

Why not allow the [HTML 5 <mark> tag](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_mark.asp) to everyone (including non mods) everywhere (including in posts)?

I think it will be useful. It would be styled with the light yellow background.